# angular-drag-and-drop-lists drop zone won't work if the dnd-list is an empty array

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angulardraganddroplists

In my scenario the drop zone initially is empty, so I created an empty array for the dnd-list. Then I noticed that angular-drag-and-drop-lists is not working - the dragover and drop callback are not called either.

I created a plunker to demo this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uMoA2bk1UB8gJVal6UAb?p=preview

It won't work until you open the scripts.js and change the array to contain something (e.g. an empty object). Is this intended behavior, or a defect?

```
// This won't work
$scope.selectedProducts = [];
// The following line works
// $scope.selectedProducts = [{}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted this to GitHub and got answer there. Basically I need to make sure that both the height and width of the dropzone is bigger than 0.

I updated the css in the plunker accordingly and made it work.

```
/* Newly added to make sure the empty dropzone is available for drop */
ul {
  height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: This! Thank you. It has solved my issue.

If the drop element has a height that is lesser than the element that is being dragged into it then the drop fails, without any console error